# Where do I place this module?

Tags: 8, theming

In Drupal 8, I created A content type (*Field_sideshow*). The requirements for a module I downloaded are the following.

- Libraries API
- jQuery Cycle plugin
- JCarousel

I downloaded the jCarousel module and placed it in modules/contrib/, the jQuery Cycle plugin in libraries/jquery.cycle/.

Where do I place the Libraries API module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Installing contributed modules (Drupal 8)](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/modules-themes/modules-8):

> The downloaded module package will be in a compressed file format such as 'tar.gz' and needs to be extracted to /modules or a subdirectory of /modules in the Drupal root directory

Given that you have a conveniently named "contrib" subfolder already under /modules, it might make sense to put it in there. But it's up to you.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/1440066    In this link They said like this IMPORTANT: Do not put the external library in the modules/libraries or sites/all/modules/libraries directories, which are the possible directories of the Libraries API module (depending on the major version of Drupal)                           why they said like this...???

Comment: That's correct. But you didn't ask where to put the library, you asked where to put the module.

Comment: Yes. you are correct. I asked wrongly. Sorry @Clive